# How to handle protected view errors in Excel VBA macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

**Introduction**. I have a local website, and one of its pages is used for downloading an Excel report by several users on their PCs. The file is automatically generated with some data from our database by the means of Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher (OBIP), so the file has an old MS Excel 97-2003 `.xls` format. However, we use Office 2019 and its newer Excel version to open `.xls` files.

**Problem occurrence**. The file contains VBA macro, which runs only once and does several `hide` and `autofit` operations based on some cells values from different sheets.
Unfortunately for me, the Excel product enables **Protected view** by default, so when a new user opens any report, he faces two problems:

- commands in `Workbook_Open` function don't work before pressing Enable button (which leads to the next problem)
- after Enabling editing there appears an error: `Application-defined or object-defined error`.

  And when debugging this error it stops on the line: `If [MyNamedcell] = "1" Then`.

**Failed attempts**. As I see, it means that there is no defined name at the moment after user enables editing and VBA runs. that's why I tried enabling editing in macro with this script:

```
If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    For Each ProtectedViewWindow In Application.ProtectedViewWindows
        ProtectedViewWindow.Activate
        Set Workbook = ProtectedViewWindow.Edit()
        Next ProtectedViewWindow
End If
```

But it gets me the [edit error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNosj.png) when opening the file: `Editing has been blocked for this file`.

And when debugging this error it stops on the line: `Set Workbook = ProtectedViewWindow.Edit()`.

I couldn't find any similar error to this one on the Internet!

**Question**. How can I prevent users from seeing the errors and successfully complete all the macro operations after the editing is enabled in [Protected view message bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcGCR.png)?

I should notice, that:

- **Enable all macros** option is somehow already turned on in every user's Excel.
- the alternative way of solving my problem is to disable all **Protected view** options in **Trust center** before working with my report, but it may be not be 100% safe, since there is a problem in macro, another new user may miss the information about disabling the options and face the problem again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I can resolve this straight away, but a couple of workarounds may be considered,

- Disable Protected View. As you mentioned, disabling all *Protected View* options in Trust Center may not be an ideal solution, but you can provide clear instructions to users on how to disable it temporarily for your specific reports. Alternatively, consider changing the file extension of the downloaded file from .xls to .xlsm, which is the format for Excel files with macros. However, this may not be desired.
- Handle 'Workbook_Open' **privately**, i.e. Check if the file is opened in *Protected View* and *exit* the macro if it is. This way, the macro will not run until the user enables editing, avoiding errors. e.g.,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Continue with the rest of VB
End Sub
```

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you. That's pretty much what I've decided to do. But instead of `Exit Sub` I show a message, which asks a user to turn off the Protected view in Excel options.

Comment: @GarryGorn All good. Agree - a quick error handler with _vbInformation_ to workaround is efficient, some are concerned about 'security' (or 'you vb doesn't work'), alongside at work people need to run multi VB anyway so...

Answer (score 1):

If anybody gets a message `Editing has been blocked for this file` when a macro starts precessing: the reason of such error may be in the way you open your file, so try another way of opening it.

In my case, the error message appeared when I opened an `.xls` file with the **Excel UI** in Protected view to reproduce the error my users faced (and I couldn't reproduce it with enabling all the Protected view options):

Excel Home → Open → Folders → Open with protected view